# Stacked Bar Graph in Excel or Matlab

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, matlab

I want to represent this graph either in matlab/excel . X-axis show the load on primary network with values ranging 0.0 to 0.9 At Y-axis there is a ratio of NSU/NCH that goes from 0.08 to 0.44 each step is of 0.04.
There are two categories CHO and NHO like NHO is represented with blue in the figure and CHO is represented with greeen in the figure. now for ratio value of 0.08 CHO is better for all value of ld_pr(x-axis)
same is for 0.4 and 0.44 NHO is better for all values of ld_pr

0.5 to 0.6 NHO(blue line) is better then from 0.6 to 0.9 again CHO is better (green line)
I want to show this either in matlab or excel. 
if some one of you can help me

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to chart this?  Any particular issue you're running into?

Comment: I have tried google if stacked column graph works didn't understand how  to start ......... bcz in stacked column graph (excel) how to put range of values for one category and other range of values for other category like i mentioned in the figure CHO and NHO two different categories and both give best result for different range of values of ld_pr

Answer (score 2):

Because you have two separate bars for CHO in some places, you have to structure your data table with 3 series:

[image]

Now you can create the graph.  The details of this will vary depending on your version of Excel.

Select the data (including the headings) in B1:D11, and choose "Bar > Stacked Bar" from the Charts tab.  That should give you a graph similar to this:

[image]

Next, select "Source Data..." from the "Chart" menu. Click the first series in the list (CHO), then click in the box for "Category (X) axis labels:" and select the NSU/NCH data (A2:A11).

Under "Chart Layout", add a Vertical Axis Title.  Edit the text as necessary.

Click to select the horizontal axis, and edit the Scale to have a Maximum of 0.9 and a Major Unit of 0.1.

Change the colors of the bars by clicking each series in turn, edit the Data Series, and change the Fill to the appropriate color.

Finally, select the legend to delete it, or click again on just the CHO2 label to delete that.  The end result should be something like this:

[image]

Comment: One more thing: the chart will be easier to read without the shadows and shading of the bars.